# How to return a JSON string representation of a data structure? (Python3)

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

If you are given a data structure (Strings, Arrays, Integers, Dictionaries) how would you return a JSON string representation of that structure? I'm aware of how to return the representation for a single data structure, but how would you design a process that can do it for all of the above listed structures?

i.e.

`array(1,"abc",2)` would be `[1,"abc",2"]`

`array('key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2')` would be `{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}`. The key of an associative array will always be a string.

Integers arrays would be converted to int strings and so on...

Below is the direction of how I would code it, but the "JSON String Representation" portion of it kind of confuses me.

```
def convertJSON(dataStruc)

    return(list(dataStruc)) # Takes whatever struc dataStruc is and turns it into a Python list
```

But this wouldnt necessarily change the data type or work for dictionaries/hash tables.

Comment: There is only a dictionary in python, what do you mean by hash tables? And also, have you tried json.dumps()?

Comment: Would want to not have to use json.dumps() or any other JSON encoders (json_encode(0), json.dumps(), etc...

Comment: So are you trying to get the same output as `json.dumps()` for each of the specified data types but with your own method?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `json.dumps()`? json module is included in core python. Unless you want to reinvent the wheel (poorly most likely), I recommend sticking to standard functions. If you want pretty printed json, use `indent=2` parameter for `json.dumps()` call.